# How can I get the old newtab in chrome back?

Tags: google-chrome

The newest stable chrome on Ubuntu has a really degraded newtab page; lots of useful features are now unavailable, like "other devices" and "Recently closed".  The search box is not good either.

So is there any solution or workaround to get back those features?

Comment: Be Polite and respectful towards the developers and the community as a whole.If you think something is not the way it should be, you can always contact the developers for `feature-request`

Answer (score 2):

There *used* to be [a way to fix this through `chrome://flags`](http://blogs.computerworld.com/internet/22878/chrome-new-tab-page) but that was removed at the beginning of the year.

Your only option now is the ["Replace New Tab Page" plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/replace-new-tab-page/cnkhddihkmmiiclaipbaaelfojkmlkja).

Answer (score 1):

The options you are missing are now located under **Main menu** (the ☰ at the upper right corner) > **Recent Tabs**.